# parsing XML with ampersand

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have a string which contains XML, I just want to parse it into Xelement, but it has an ampersand. I still have a problem parseing it with HtmlDecode. Any suggestions?

```
string test = " <MyXML><SubXML><XmlEntry Element="test" value="wow&" /></SubXML></MyXML>"; 

XElement.Parse(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(test));
```

I also added these methods to replace those characters, but I am still getting XMLException.

```
string encodedXml = test.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&apos;");
XElement myXML = XElement.Parse(encodedXml);
```

t
or Even tried it with this:

```
string newContent=  SecurityElement.Escape(test);
XElement myXML = XElement.Parse(newContent);
```

Answer (score 27):

Ideally the XML is escaped properly prior to your code consuming it. If this is beyond your control you could write a regex. Do not use the String.Replace method unless you're absolutely sure the values do not contain other escaped items.

For example, `"wow&amp;".Replace("&", "&amp;")` results in `wow&amp;amp;` which is clearly undesirable.

Regex.Replace can give you more control to avoid this scenario, and can be written to only match "&" symbols that are not part of other characters, such as `&lt;`, something like:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(test, "&(?!(amp|apos|quot|lt|gt);)", "&amp;");
```

The above works, but admittedly it doesn't cover the variety of other characters that start with an ampersand, such as `&nbsp;` and the list can grow.

A more flexible approach would be to decode the content of the value attribute, then re-encode it. If you have `value="&wow&amp;"` the decode process would return `"&wow&"` then re-encoding it would return `"&amp;wow&amp;"`, which is desirable. To pull this off you could use this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(test, @"value=\""(.*?)\""", m => "value=\"" +
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(m.Groups[1].Value)) +
    "\"");
var doc = XElement.Parse(result);
```

Bear in mind that the above regex only targets the contents of the value attribute. If there are other areas in the XML structure that suffer from the same issue then it can be tweaked to match them and replace their content in a similar fashion.

---

**EDIT:** updated solution that should handle content between tags as well as anything between double quotes. Be sure to test this thoroughly. Attempting to manipulate XML/HTML tags with regex is not favorable as it can be error prone and over-complicated. Your case is somewhat special since you need to sanitize it first in order to make use of it.

```
string pattern = "(?<start>>)(?<content>.+?(?<!>))(?<end><)|(?<start>\")(?<content>.+?)(?<end>\")";
string result = Regex.Replace(test, pattern, m =>
            m.Groups["start"].Value +
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(m.Groups["content"].Value)) +
            m.Groups["end"].Value);
var doc = XElement.Parse(result);
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect, but is it possible to use Regex for XML values as well. Cause as you said this only works for attributes. For example in this case: <MyXML>this & that</MyXML>

Comment: @paradisonoir: yep, see my edit. As I said, make sure you test it thoroughly.

Comment: This approach seems to assume "one element at a time".  Is that correct?  I have a similar problem to the OP where I'm trying to clean an XML file prior to loading it, but my line has multiple nodes and the results are not what is expected.  Is there a way to apply this pattern to a line with multiple nodes <a><b foo="asdf&fdsa"><c>hello&world</c></b></a>?

Comment: @Ben: try this pattern with the snippet that uses named groups above: `string pattern = "(?<=>)(?<content>[^>]+)(?=<)|(?<start>\")(?<content>.+?)(?<end>\")";`

Comment: Minor point, but &nbsp; isn't an XML entity, it's an (X)HTML one; strictly speaking it's not valid XML anyway. As far as I can remember there are only 5 entities in XML: amp, lt, gt, apos and quot. However, you would need to check for &#<char code>; entities.

Comment: ampersand could also be followed by number codes. &apos; can also be represented by &#39; or &#039; or &#x27; use: string result = Regex.Replace(test, @"&(?!(quot|amp|apos|lt|gt|#x?\d{2,3});)", "&amp;");

Comment: This solution causes me different encoding problems with an é getting turned into an &eacute; I think HtmlEncode is now encoding too much.

Comment: Was a quick lifesaver. Thanks amigo 

Answer (score 14):

Your string doesn't contain valid XML, that's the issue. You need to change your string to:

```
<MyXML><SubXML><XmlEntry Element="test" value="wow&amp;" /></SubXML></MyXML>"
```

Comment: thanks, but I was just wondering how? and what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Depends. If you're always parsing from a string object, you could do a simple test=test.Replace("&","&amp;");

Comment: well, that replaced the character, but when I want to parse, I still have some problem. I added my new methods.

Comment: That's because you replaced too much. You should only need to replace the amperes and. If you replace the greater than and less than symbols, you won't have any tags at all.

Answer (score 3):

HtmlEncode will not do the trick, it will probably create even more ampersands (for instance, a ' might become ", which is an Xml entity reference, which are the following:

```
&amp;   & 
&apos;  ' 
&quot;  " 
&lt;    < 
&gt;    >
```

But it might you get things like &nbsp, which is fine in html, but not in Xml. Therefore, like everybody else said, correct the xml first by making sure any character that is **NOT PART OF THE ACTUAL MARKUP OF YOUR XML** (that is to say, **anything INSIDE your xml as a variable or text**) and that occurs in the entity reference list is translated to their corresponding entity (so < would become <). If the text containing the illegal character is text inside an xml node, you could take the easy way and surround the text with a CDATA element, this won't work for attributes though.

Comment: but how do you suggest to do that?

Comment: Well, I would suggest doing BEFORE you create the Xml file, assuming you are the one doing the creating of course. If you are not in control of the creation of the xml file (because for instance it is downloaded from somewhere), I suggest you contact the person responsible and have him sanitize the xml before sending it to you.

Comment: If you are in control of the creation of the xml file, use a RegEx (sorry, I suck at RegEx can't give example) or just a chained replacec like so: string.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("'", "&quot;").etc.etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Filip's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54199291/3626160) answer is on the right track, but you can hijack the `System.Xml.XmlDocument` class to do this for you without an entire new utility function.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string xmlEscapedString = (doc.CreateTextNode("Unescaped '&' containing string that would have broken your xml")).OuterXml;
```

Answer (score 1):

The ampersant makes the XML invalid. This cannot be fixed by a stylesheet so you need to write code with some other tool or code in VB/C#/PHP/Delphi/Lisp/Etc. to remove it or to translate it to &amp;.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest and best approach. Works with all characters and allows to parse XML for any web service call i.e. SharePoint ASMX.

```
public string XmlEscape(string unescaped)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            var node = doc.CreateElement("root");
            node.InnerText = unescaped;
            return node.InnerXml;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is not valid XML, it will not parse. If it contains an ampersand on its own, it's not valid XML. Contrary to HTML, XML is very strict.

Answer (score 0):

You should 'encode' rather than decode. But calling HttpUtility.HtmlEncode will not help you as it will encode your '<' and '>' symbols as well and your string will no longer be an XML.

I think that for this case the best solution would be to replace '&' with '& amp;' (with no space)

Comment: but how do you suggest to do that?

Comment: test.Replace("&", "&amp;") will do the trick I guess. You don't need Replace("<", "&lt;") and all other staff just because these symbols are used by markup.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider writing your own XMLDocumentScanner. That's what [NekoHTML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nekohtml) is doing to have the ability to ignore ampersands not used as entity references.