# How to unescape special characters in c#

Tags: c#, xelement

I have the following code

```
XElement element = new XElement("test", "a&b");
```

where

`element.LastNode` contains the value `"a&amp;b"`.

i wanted to be it `"a&b"`.

How do i replace this?

Comment: which language are you running?

Comment: i tried to do XElement element = new XElement("test", HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("a&b"));

Comment: & is not a valid character in XML as it introduces an entity code. &amp; is used for & in XML.

Comment: But if i want to replace how do i do that

Comment: You can't! Otherwise your XML would be no longer valid XML.

Comment: @user2392525 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473826/parsing-xml-with-ampersand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait a moment,

> <test>a&b</test>

is not valid XML. You cannot make XML that looks like this. This is [clarified by the XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax).

`&` has special meaning, it denotes an escaped character that may otherwise be invalid. An  `'&'` character is encoded as `&amp;` in XML.

---

for what its worth, this is invalid HTML for the same reason.

> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> a&b </body> </html>

---

If I write the code,

```
const string Value = "a&b";
var element = new XElement("test", Value);
Debug.Assert(
    string.CompareOrdinal(Value, element.Value) == 0,
    "XElement is mad");
```

it runs without error, `XElement` encodes and decodes to and from XML as necessary.

**To unescape or decode the XML element you simply read `XElement.Value`.**

If you want to make a document that looks like

> <test>a&b</test>

you can but it is not XML or HTML, tools for working with HTML or XML won't intentionally help you. You'll have make your own Readers, Writers and Parsers.

Answer (score 3):

The & is a reserved character so it will allways be encoded. So you have to decode:

Is this an option:
[HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Usage:

```
string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("a&amp;b");
// returns "a&b"
```

Comment: this works but i cannot assign this string value to Xelement.Lastnode

Comment: Of course you can. But it will be automatically encoded.

Comment: you could just read `element.Value`, you should be careful HTML decoding XML. It works fine for `&` but not all characters get escaped the same way by both standards.

Comment: @user2392525 adding `a&b` without encoding it would result in syntactically incorrect xml.  `<test>a&b</test>` has a syntax error. `<test>a&amp;b</test>` is correct. It only requires you to decode the values

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
public static string GetTextFromHTML(String htmlstring)
    {
        // replace all tags with spaces...
       htmlstring= Regex.Replacehtmlstring)@"<(.|\n)*?>", " ");

       // .. then eliminate all double spaces
       while (htmlstring).Contains("  "))
       {
           htmlstring= htmlstring.Replace("  ", " ");
        }

       // clear out non-breaking spaces and & character code
       htmlstring = htmlstring.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
       htmlstring = htmlstring.Replace("&amp;", "&");

       return htmlstring;
    }
```